# Using ubuntu and windows 10 natively on a machine without dualbootinb

Tags: hard-drive

I recently installed ubuntu 17.04 on my machine but still had to use windows from time to time , so my idea was using a vm.
It turned out that using a vm was very slow and the performance was not enough for me , so i think my only option now is running windows on my machine natively.
I don't want to dualboot since i tried that before and i saw that windows doesn't play well with other bootloaders on the same machine.
I had an idea of buying another hard drive and installing windows on it and simply swapping the drives when needing to use windows (i have a laptop and the hard drive slot can be easily accessed).
I don't see any possible issued with doing that and just wanted to get an opinion if it will work , or if there is an easier way around.

Comment: VMs will always be a lot slower. From what you're saying, it sounds like you should go for a dual boot machine. Yes, Windows updates sometimes screw up your dual boot setup (had that happen to me a couple of times), but it's easy to fix (by re-installing GRUB) most of the time.

Comment: I tried reinstalling grub using a couple of different tools and neither one of them could fix my linux installation , ended up uninstalling windows , and installing ubuntu instead.

Comment: From our good friends over at Askubuntu here is what works... and usually pretty well... I've used this with Ubuntu and Windows 10 and it works flawlessly, even with Windows Updates: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot. The key: Install Windows first.

Answer (score 0):

Drive swapping is a viable solution.  However, there is a method I use to dual boot Windows and Linux Mint.  This works with most modern computers that let you select the boot device as the computer posts.  This usually comes up at the same time as the BIOS option.  On my Dell, I would hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to go into BIOS and <kbd>F12</kbd> to select a boot device.  A boot device would be anything configured to boot from in BIOS, such as hard drives, CD/DVD, USB, and network.  I simply disabled my Windows drive by unplugging it to be 100% sure I didnt nuke my Windows drive (although you could disable it in BIOS).  I installed Linux on the other drive and then plugged my Windows drive back in.  Now, I can reboot and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to select which hard drive I want to boot from.  I dont have to deal with bootloader confusion.  This also allows me to use my Linux drive as a raw drive in VirtualBox.  I can boot my Linux Mint machine from inside Windows when I dont want to reboot.  This also works the other way around.

Comment: I use a laptop so i only have one hard drive slot.

Comment: @DirtyAxe does it have a DVD bay you dont use?  You can always install a SATA drive in there with an adapter